# Common code chunk for sync and async chunks in case of vite

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, vite, rollup

Can't async chunks reuse code from sync chunks in case of vite/rollup? like there is chunks: 'all' property inside splitChunksPlugin in case of webpack. Is there any alternative to this property in case of vite/rollup?

Read documentation of vite and rollup, was not able to find any alternative for splitsChunks.chunk property